# An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade, how to solve it?

Tags: upgrade

I'm on maverick, and want to upgrade to natty.
I went to `update manager` and clicked upgrade. while it's calculating upgrade an error appeared:

[image: an error appear]

What should I do now?

---

#### Edit:

I also try upgrade from Ubuntu alternate CD, but getting same error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this bug] ( https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/146536) on Bugzilla

A work-around:

- Run `synaptic`
- <kbd>Refresh</kbd> to pull package lists
- <kbd>Mark all upgrades</kbd>
- Search for any packages you know got removed by an `apt-get dist-upgrade` if you ran it. For me, I told it to reinstall pidgin, AccessGrid, and ubuntu-desktop (which installed two other trivial packages).
- <kbd>Apply</kbd>

Comment: thanks Rinzwind, I used upgrade to natty from live CD :)